# Check log-linearity of a continuous variable to predict survival

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, log-linear

I have the following survival data: cases with a continuous variable `risk_factor` wich higher values having a higher HR (1.026, CI: [1.017-1.034], p = 2.03e-09) for survival (after running regression Cox model). I want to verify the log-linearity of the continuous variable `risk_factor` for predicting the survival. How could I do it? What would be the explanation and the code. Does it make sense to do it? Can it reinforce the information given by the Cox regression model?

```
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
timespan_censored = c(round(runif(450, 0, 4500), digit = 0), 
                  round(runif(150, 0, 1200), digit = 0))

risk_factor = c(runif(450, min=10, max=80), 
            runif(150, min=20, max=100))
status = c(rep(0, 450), rep(1, 150))
timespan_censored = c(round(runif(450, 0, 4500), digit = 0), 
                  round(runif(150, 0, 1200), digit = 0))
df_try = data.frame(status, timespan_censored, risk_factor)
cox_mod = coxph(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ risk_factor, data = df_try) %>% summary()
cox_mod
```

this is the output:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ risk_factor, 
data = df_try)

n= 600, number of events= 150 

                coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)    
risk_factor 0.025294  1.025617 0.004219 5.995 2.03e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

            exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
risk_factor     1.026      0.975     1.017     1.034

Concordance= 0.629  (se = 0.024 )
Rsquare= 0.062   (max possible= 0.953 )
Likelihood ratio test= 38.28  on 1 df,   p=6.133e-10
Wald test            = 35.94  on 1 df,   p=2.032e-09
Score (logrank) test = 37.31  on 1 df,   p=1.007e-09

ggcoxfunctional(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ risk_factor, data = df_try, xlim = c(10,110), ylim = c(-0.5,1.0))
```

[image: output of of risk factor not transformed]

```
ggcoxfunctional(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ log(risk_factor), data = df_try, xlim = c(2,5), ylim = c(-0.35,1.0))
```

[image: output of of risk factor log transformed]

```
ggcoxfunctional(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ sqrt(risk_factor), data = df_try, xlim = c(3,10), ylim = c(-0.35,1.0))
```

[image: output of of sqrt of risk factor]

```
library(rms)
cox_mod_spline = coxph(Surv(timespan_censored,status)~ rcs(risk_factor,6))
cox_mod_spline
res = residuals(cox_mod_spline, type = "martingale")
plot(df_try$risk_factor, res)
```

[image: plot of the residuals of cox regression with 6 splines against risk factor]

```
cox_mod_spline = coxph(Surv(timespan_censored,status)~ rcs(risk_factor,4))
cox_mod_spline
res = residuals(cox_mod_spline, type = "martingale")
plot(df_try$risk_factor, res)
lines(loess.smooth(df_try$risk_factor, res), lwd = 4, col="blue")
```

[image: loess line added to previous graph]

Comment: The answer might depend on correlations with other predictors and numbers of events. Please read [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/362553/28500), which includes information about using martingale residuals or splines of the continuous predictor to evaluate linearity; also [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/361972/28500) for related discussion and some useful links. If you still have unanswered questions on evaluating linearity with respect to your log-transformed continuous predictor, please edit this question to provide the further details that you need clarified.

Comment: The default choice of axis limits in `ggcoxfunctional` is not very good, as you might infer from discussion on the pages I linked to above. Specify the limits yourself (with `xlim` and `ylim` arguments) so that the y axis covers a range between -2 and +1 and so the x axis covers the complete range of your data, and post the new graphs instead, for a more complete look at what you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very helpful comment @Edm. I'm trying to read all the details in the link you provided. It seems that the `rms` package is a package to be used when dealing with survival although I have to say that the `survival`and `survminer`packages are more beginner friendly. As I did a univariate cox regression, obtaining the Martingale residuals could be a good option. I performed the 2 transformations of variables. So I guess that now I have to choose the transformation that looks the most like a straight line. But none of the plots seem to do the job well

Comment: Thanks (again!) for the good tip @Edm. I changed the axes of the graphs and updated the pictures. I still don't see a model which is definitely better than the other ones.

Comment: Try a restricted cubic spline transformation of your `risk_factor`. Without fully learning the `rms` package you can still load it to get its `rcs()` function for a standard `coxph()` call, for example: `coxph(Surv(time,status)~ rcs(risk_factor,3)`, for a spline with 3 knots (you might want/need to use more). Plot martingale residuals from the coxph object _with the spline transformation_ against `risk_factor`; a reasonably flat line shows you handled non-linearity with the spline. You'll have to plot that yourself as `ggcoxfunctional()` only shows residuals from the null model.

Comment: Ok @Edm. So i used 6! knots and plotted the residual against the the risk factors

Comment: Add a loess fit to that last plot to show a reasonably flat relation and you're done. Consider putting together your work into an answer to your own question; that's OK on this site.

Comment: thank you very much @EdM. After your comment, I added a loess fit to the last plot. What should be the best interpretation of the analysis? "using splines with 4 knots, the variable risk factor reasonably approached a constant 0 value of the residuals"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84106/discussion-between-edm-and-ecjb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fit a Cox model that relaxes the linearity assumption for the `risk_factor` on the log hazard scale, using, e.g., splines. You could compare this model with the linear fit using a likelihood ratio test and see if the effect is linear or not. If it is nonlinear, you can depict it with an effects plot.

The code below illustrates these steps with your simulated data:

```
library("survival")
library("lattice")
library("splines")

# simulate the data
timespan_censored <- c(round(runif(450, 0, 4500), digit = 0), 
                       round(runif(150, 0, 1200), digit = 0))
risk_factor <- c(runif(450, min = 10, max = 80), 
                 runif(150, min = 20, max = 100))
status <- c(rep(0, 450), rep(1, 150))
timespan_censored <- c(round(runif(450, 0, 4500), digit = 0), 
                       round(runif(150, 0, 1200), digit = 0))
df_try <- data.frame(status, timespan_censored, risk_factor)

# fit a Cox model with a linear effect for 'risk_factor'
cox_mod1 <- coxph(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ risk_factor, data = df_try)

# fit a Cox model with a nonlinear effect for 'risk_factor' using natural cubic splines
cox_mod2 <- coxph(Surv(timespan_censored, status) ~ ns(risk_factor, 4), data = df_try)

# likelihood ratio test for linearity
anova(cox_mod1, cox_mod2)

# Create an effect plot to depict the relationship
ND <- with(df_try, data.frame(risk_factor = seq(min(risk_factor), 
                                                max(risk_factor), length.out = 500)))

prs <- predict(cox_mod2, newdata = ND, type = "lp", se.fit = TRUE)
ND$pred <- prs[[1]]
ND$se <- prs[[2]]
ND$lo <- ND$pred - 1.96 * ND$se
ND$up <- ND$pred + 1.96 * ND$se

xyplot(pred + lo + up ~ risk_factor, data = ND,
       type = "l", col = "black", lwd = 2, lty = c(1, 2, 2),
       abline = list(h = 0, lty = 2, lwd = 2, col = "red"),
       xlab = "Risk Factor", ylab = "log Hazard Ratio")
```

You can find more examples in my [Survival Analysis in R Companion](http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/emc/ep03_%20survival%20analysis%20in%20r%20companion) for my [survival course](http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/EP03.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very good answer @DimitrisRizopoulos. I'm definitely going to have a look to your course and your blog and make the practical cases. However, I have some questions: 1. Although it fits the log hazard ratio is 0 for the intermediate value, it is a bit far off in the extreme value. No? 2. What should be the best interpretation of the analysis? "using cubic splines with 4 knots, the variable risk factor reasonably approached a constant 0 value of the log hazard ratio"?